# Firebase. Can't find Rules tab at Realtime Database window. Why?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, firebase-console

I'm trying to change rules to my Realtime Database. but there is not such tab.

[image]

Comment: Can you please put up a screenshot for the same? Or where you are exactly looking?

Comment: @TanishqSharma , added image

Comment: I suggest you contact firebase support.

Comment: That looks like a browser issue as the header (the blue area at the top) is larger than it should be. First thing is to try a different browser just to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @Jay, It made no difference

Comment: It's working fine for me so as Andre suggested, reach out to firebase support.

Comment: @AndréKool  yes, I have contacted to the support. They suggested problem is in browser's cache. I cleared it. It's not

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 2):

Same here. A workaround is to access your project using direct link.

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<<'projet_name'>>/database/rules

I've contacted Firebase support and here's another workaround: adding ?hl=en on the URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to: [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)
2. Choose Your Project From The Tile View
3. Once you have entered the project view, click on Database tab.

[image]

Once you click on it,

You will be able to see two tabs on top.

[image: Rules Tab]

Comment: There is no such kind of tab "Rules"

Comment: Try accessing it this way:

**Make sure you are logged in**

https://console.firebase.google.com/project/`<your-project-name>`/database/rules

Comment: Hm, I can enter to Rules page, but no tab. I signed in with another account and I have the tab there. I think the problem is in my account

Comment: Yes, perhaps. But did this solve your problem?

Comment: Not at all. The support offered to use "?hl=en" at the end of the link and it displays correct. But logcat in  Android Studio when debuging says  "W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found". So that Realtime database doesn't work. But it works with another account

Comment: Have you added their dependencies?

Answer (score -1):

Go to project -> select Database Tab -> there you will find the realtime database tab (these are the features they are showing) -> click on Realtime Database and create it --> now this will open Database Dashboard with Data, Rules, Backup and Usage Tabs.

Open Rules Tabs:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Make like this, problem will get solved.